# Angularjs node js mysql crud

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js

I want to build a crud web application using mysql nodejs and angularjs. Please tell me how to do this.

I tried to build this application but I'm facing so many problems and errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create simple nodejs application with mysql database.
For client side first use simple html and check your application whether it's working good or not.

Help for this code is here,
[Example of nodejs with mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql)

Then try to create Client side interface using angular
there is no any changes from your server side code just need to create user interface at client side using angular.

start you application in angular from [here](https://angular.io/)